# how to get mimetype of file in command line

Tags: php, linux

Get mimetype with finfo from file

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $finfo->file($file);
```

Get mimetype with finfo from string

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $finfo->buffer($file);
```

Get mimetype in command line from file

```
$type = shell_exec('file -bi '.escapeshellarg(realpath($file)));
```

How to get mimetype in command line from string?

Comment: Please clarify. As far as i can tell your last line of code will get you your mimetype as a string..

Comment: I doubt this is even possible. I see no reason why anyone would build that. It would look something like `file -bi --from-string=$(cat /path/to/file)` anyway. Or were you planning on writing a PNG yourself?

Comment: I need to get the mimetype from the file as a string.. not a file

Answer (score 0):

As your question tag says "php, linux", you better try this one.

```
$ mimetype <filename>
```

Example:

```
$ mimetype index.php
index.php : application/x-php
```